# where's the carrot in tf tutorial?

Tags: ros, transform, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tf tutorial and am a little stuck on the broadcast frame page:
[tf/tutorials/adding a frame](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20%28C%2B%2B%29)

I am able to get it to run, but only see turtle1 and turtle2, no carrot.  This makes sense to me, since I see where turtle2 is spawned (in the listener code) and no place where a carrot is spawned.  It wouldn't really matter, except turtle2's behavior looks not correct-- it is not going to a spot 2m in front of turtle1 (where the carrot should be), but is doing something close to that, so I'd like to get the visual indicator for that.

I get that there may not be a drawing of a carrot, so I'm fine with just using a third turtle or some other visual indicator of the target.

I think that somehow I need to spawn the carrot, either in the broadcast frame code or in the listener code.  Suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9505/where%27s-the-carrot-in-tf-tutorial?/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2011-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, both of you are right. The carrot is two meters to the left of `turtle1`. This might not be what you expect, but the tutorial just states that

> "The `carrot1` frame is 2 meters offset
> from the `turtle1` frame."

I have edited the Wiki page to make that more clear. If you look at the code, this is exactly what we stated:

```
transform.setOrigin( tf::Vector3(0.0, 2.0, 0.0) );
```

The three values are (x, y, z), and by convention, x is forward, y is left and z is up (not used for a 2D turtle). If you want the carrot to be two meters in front of the first turtle, change that line to:

```
transform.setOrigin( tf::Vector3(2.0, 0.0, 0.0) );
```

To answer your original question: [@davo](http://answers.ros.org/users/456/davo/) is right, for visualization, the best option is to do the following while the turtlesim is running:

1. start RViz: `rosrun rviz rviz`
2. click "Add -> TF"
3. make sure that the checkboxes "show Names" and "Frames -> all Enabled" are ticked
4. in "Global Options -> fixed frame" select world

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1